# Изменение CSS свойства position через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, меню, position

Есть адаптивное фиксированное меню

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var touch   = $('#touch-menu');
var menu    = $('#menu ul');

$(touch).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 790 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
        menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Нужно, чтобы при клике на `#touch-menu` сменилось свойство `position` c `fixed` на `absolute` у блока `#menu`.

Пробовал так

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var touch   = $('#touch-menu');
    var menu    = $('#menu ul');
    var msld    = $('#menu');

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
        msld.style.position = "absolute";
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 790 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Выдает ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> msld.style.position = "absolute";
> ```

Выбери один из следующих вариантов. Вероятно, первый.

```
msld.css('position', "absolute");
msld[0].style.position = "absolute";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
msld.css('position', 'absolute');
```